# Django-tagging: Grabbing objects by specifying multiple tags?

Tags: django, django-tagging

I currently have an entry in `urls.py` which fetches lone permalinks for my bugs:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

from tagging.views import tagged_object_list

from bugs.models import Bug

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Example:
    # (r'^workarounds/', include('workarounds.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below and add 'django.contrib.admindocs' 
    # to INSTALLED_APPS to enable admin documentation:
    # (r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    (r'^$', 'django.views.generic.simple.direct_to_template', {'template':'homepage.html'}),

    (r'^bugs/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', 'bugs.views.bug_detail'),
    (r'^bugs/tagged/(?P<tag>[^/]+)/$', 
    'tagging.views.tagged_object_list',
    {
        'queryset_or_model': Bug,
        'template_name' : 'tag/lone.html'}),
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

So if I specified a url of say, `bugs/tagged/firefox` it would bring up firefox tags. How could I make it filter out by multiple tags? eg: `firefox+css` would return all objects tagged with `firefox` and `css`.

Comment: What are you actually asking? How to construct the url or how to construct the tagging queryset?

Comment: Well I'm guessing I could use the same exact regex except a bit modified but the queryset part I'm not sure about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to build your own view instead of using `tagging.views.tagged_object_list`.

```
(r'^bugs/tagged/(?P<tags>[-\w+]+)/$', your_tag_view)
```

In your view, get a list of the tags you are searching for:

```
tags = tags.split('+')
```

Then, use the `TaggedItem.objects.get_by_model` query, which conveniently will accept a list of tags:

```
from tagging.models import TaggedItem
bugs = TaggedItem.objects.get_by_model(Bug, tags)
```

Comment: The django-tagging source is a bit more helpful than the documentation: http://code.google.com/p/django-tagging/source/browse/trunk/tagging/models.py

Comment: This worked for me, but I had to update the url with the missing + symbol: (r'^bugs/tagged/(?P<tags>[-\w+]+)/$', your_tag_view) or it would only work on one tag at a time